# cex.var not working... How to change size of variables font in coefplot

Tags: r, plot, coefplot

I'm trying to plot the coefficients (and 95% CIs) from a regression model in R but the variable names are tiny. I'm trying to increase the size of the names but the line `cex.var=3.0` in`coefplot(model, cex.var=3.0)` doesn't seem to be changing anything.

I've tried: `cex=3.0`, `cex.vars=3.0`, and `cex.lab=3.0` to no avail.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Please consider to add a minimal, reproducible example, as well as any call to extra packages.

Comment: There are multiple versions of `coefplot`, some of which appear to use base graphics and others using ggplot2/grid methods. (There is also a Stata-coefplot.) You should construct an example and edit your question to include library call to the package where you are getting `coefplot`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The plot is made using `ggplot2` so you need to use theme. Something like this

```
data(iris)
model <- lm(Sepal.Width ~ Sepal.Length, data=iris)
coefplot(model) + 
theme(text = element_text(size=30),
      axis.text.x = element_text(angle=90, vjust=1))
```

Comment: thank you! this worked. I could't figure how to work these `ggplot2` commands into `coefplot`.